# Pass variable from express server to react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

So I am using 
[react universally](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally) and I want to pass some variable value to the react application from the server without having to do an ajax request after it's loaded. The react application is loaded like:

```
const someVariable = 'some variable';
// The React application middleware.
app.get('*', reactApplication);
```

How can I pass it to down so that it will be available in the react application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server-side variables to Client-Side with React-Engine and Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359872/server-side-variables-to-client-side-with-react-engine-and-express)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header property in `express/node-server:`

```
res.writeHead(statusCode , {header properties})    
(fast, not cached by default)
```

-or-

Parse your index file and inject your property right into the head (not fast, can be cached to be faster) and check for that property in react with

```
document.getElementById('propertyId')
```

-or-

```
document.getElementByTagName('propertyTag')
```